# Creating triggers and selecting the sum of shipped order with two variables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, triggers, sum

I currently have this assignment where we are supposed to create triggers to block the insert of a shipment depending on whether they exceed the total or not.

I have to sum all the shipped quantities and group them by order **and** product number.

Here are my tables to give an outlook:

*My variables are in French, I'm sorry*

```
CREATE TABLE LigneLivraison
(noLivraison            NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 noProduit                      NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 noCommande                     NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 quantiteLivree     NUMBER(19)      NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (noLivraison),
 FOREIGN KEY (noLivraison) REFERENCES Livraison,
 FOREIGN KEY (noProduit)   REFERENCES Produit,
 FOREIGN KEY (noCommande)  REFERENCES Commande
)
/
CREATE TABLE LigneCommande
(noCommande             NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 noProduit              NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 quantite               NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 CHECK (quantite > 0),
 PRIMARY KEY (noCommande, noProduit),
 FOREIGN KEY (noCommande) REFERENCES Commande,
 FOREIGN KEY (noProduit)  REFERENCES Produit
)
/
```

When I try to execute it, Oracle mentions that the SQL command does not end correctly

Here is what I have so far for the first trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bloquerInsertionCommande
BEFORE INSERT
        ON LigneLivraison

REFERENCING
        NEW AS NouvelleLivraison


FOR EACH ROW


BEGIN
        SELECT LigneLivraison.noProduit, LigneLivraison.noCommande, LigneCommande.quantite, SUM(LigneLivraison.quantiteLivree) shipped, (LigneCommande.quantite - shipped) Total
        FROM LigneLivraison, LigneCommande
        WHERE LigneLivraison.noCommande = LigneCommande.noCommande
        GROUP BY noCommande AND noProduit;

        IF :NouvelleLivraison.quantiteLivree > Total THEN raise_application_error(-20100, 'La quantite a livrer est trop elevee');

END IF;
END;
/
```

Since shipping can be made seperately and an *x* number of times, I need to add all the same product of a certain order number to compare it with what the client originally ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Your create table commands are not working as there are multiple issues as mentioned in the comments inline in following code:

```
CREATE TABLE LigneLivraison
(noLivraison            NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 noProduit                      NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 noCommande                     NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 quantiteLivree     NUMBER(19)      NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (noLivraison),
 FOREIGN KEY (noLivraison) REFERENCES Livraison(pk_column_name_of_livraison_table), -- you need to add column name of referencing table here
 FOREIGN KEY (noProduit)   REFERENCES Produit(pk_column_name_of_produit_table), -- you need to add column name of referencing table here
 FOREIGN KEY (noCommande)  REFERENCES Commande(pk_column_name_of_commande_table) -- you need to add column name of referencing table here
);  -- ending statement with ;
-- / -- this is not needed in sql statements

CREATE TABLE LigneCommande
(noCommande             NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 noProduit              NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL,
 quantite               NUMBER(19)              NOT NULL CHECK (quantite > 0), -- combined it in single column level constraint
 PRIMARY KEY (noCommande, noProduit),
 FOREIGN KEY (noCommande) REFERENCES Commande(pk_column_name_of_commande_table), -- you need to add column name of referencing table here
 FOREIGN KEY (noProduit)  REFERENCES Produit(pk_column_name_of_produit_table) -- you need to add column name of referencing table here
);
--/
```

Also, `pk` of referencing table is written in comment for clarity. You can use `pk` or `unique key` in `references` clause according to your requirement.

After your `tables` are created properly then only you will be able to identify proper error in the `trigger`.